# Changing the location files included in a pull request, GitHub

Tags: github, pull-request

Once I've created a pull request on GitHub, how can I modify the proposed location of the new files I've included in the pull request if the new files are binary files like an image? I've gotten a request to move one of the images I've included in a request to another directory, but I'm not sure how to do that. I can't edit the file in the GitHub GUI because the image is a binary file.

Comment: Add a commit that moves the file, and push. You can optionally rebase and squash the two commits in a single one, to make as if you made the right thing in a single commit.

Comment: If you're not very familiar with Git, like you're just submitting artwork to the project via the Github web site, you can reply to let them know that and ask if they'd make the changes for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That it's a binary file doesn't matter, use [`git mv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) to rename it like any other file. You can update a pull request with more changes by pushing them.

1. `git checkout mybranch`
2. `git mv oldfile newfile`
3. `git commit`
4. `git push`

Optionally you could use `git rebase -i master` (assuming you branched off master) before 4 to rewrite history so the file was always in the right location. This avoids having "fixup" commits and makes reviewing a bit easier.

If you're just figuring out how to move files, you probably shouldn't mess with rebase, but you should [read about it](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) because it's one of the most powerful features of Git.